# Why is @Input property standardLinks been overwritten?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm currently working on a footer, where I want to display dynamically some links. The standard links should switch accordingly to the property company (which works just fine), but I also want them to change, if they are passed explicitly in the footer.ts file (see property customizedLinks).
Apparently the @Input property standardLinks in the links.component.ts file seems to be overwritten, so that the links won't switch when passed explicitly.

Do you have any idea, how to solve this?

Here is my code:

link.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Link} from "../models/link.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-links',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let link of standardLinks">
      <a [href]="link.url">{{ link.name }}</a>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./links.component.css']
})
export class LinksComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() company: 'a' | 'b' = 'a';
  @Input() standardLinks: Link[] = [];


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateFooterLinks();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.company) {
      this.updateFooterLinks()
    }
  }

  private updateFooterLinks() {
    if (this.company === 'b') {
      this.standardLinks = [
        new Link('Link 1b', 'blabla.com'),
        new Link('Link 2b', 'blabla.com'),
        new Link('Link 3b', 'blabla.com'),
      ];
    } else {
      this.standardLinks = [
        new Link('Link 1a', 'blabla.com'),
        new Link('Link 2a', 'blabla.com'),
        new Link('Link 3a', 'blabla.com'),
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

footer.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
        <h2>Legal 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <footer>
      <span>Brand 1</span>
      <app-links></app-links>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2>Legal 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <footer>
      <span>Brand 2</span>
      <app-links
        [standardLinks]="customizedLinks"
      ></app-links>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2>Legal 3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <footer>
      <span>Brand 3</span>
      <app-links [company]="'b'"></app-links>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

footer.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Link} from "../models/link.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  customizedLinks : Link[] = [
    new Link('bla 1', 'blabla.com'),
    new Link('bla 2', 'blabla.com'),
    new Link('bla 3', 'blabla.com'),
  ]


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

The expected behavior should be:

Footer

Legal 1

Brand 1
Link 1a
Link 2a
Link 3a

Legal 2

Brand 2
bla 1
bla 2
bla 3

Legal 3

Brand 3
Link 1b
Link 2b
Link 3b

Note that the code has been simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see you're overwritting the value explicitly w/o putting any condition:

[image]

In a nutshell, you can solve your problem by adding a condition to your `updateFooterLinks` function in `ngOnInit` as follows:

```html
ngOnInit(): void {
  if (!this.standardLinks.length) {
    this.updateFooterLinks();
  }
}
```

OR

```html
ngOnInit(): void {
  !this.standardLinks.length && this.updateFooterLinks();
}
```

Bonus: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1cyz3z

One more thing.. Why you're calling `updateFooterLinks` in `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, they're arguably *more* harmful in answers than in questions and they're entirely useless in questions. Take the time to copy & paste the actual code *as* code.

Comment: @Abder Thank you so much for your answer. I was actually trying to solve the problem by adding the condition `if (!this.standardLinks)` to the ngOnInit() and not `!this.standardLinks.length` as you suggested, but I wasn't getting the expected behavior. Since this is a bug in a bigger project, I also wasn't sure about the ngOnChanges() role in it, that is way I preferred to copy it in my code, but I guess it can be left out.